# Account of caller of action

Tags: action

Is there a way to get the account of the caller within an action?

If not, I would need to add an extra parameter to the action containing the action name and then do some verification. It would be nicer to not have the extra parameter.

In that context what is the `current_receiver` (is it the contract) and how differs this from `self` (the contract)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The caller of the action (which is simlar to msg.sender in ETH) is not available in the action itself. As actions can be called with several user permissions at the same time there is no unique caller.

If you require a particular user permission you need to provide that as an extra parameter and call `require_auth(user)`

`current_receiver` is the account name that the contract belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

Update, it's just called "receiver" now. According to [the latest docs](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/communication-model):

> "receiver" is the account that is currently processing the action. "code" is the account that authorized the contract.