# Referring to permissioned account within contract code?

Tags: smart-contract, cleos, permissions

I've created a table within a contract where I want to store user information.  the `.emplace()` method's first parameter specifies the "scope" (I guess) for data to be stored and thus the user account

when I create the transaction I pass in the account that has permission via -p.  something like:

`cleos push action MyContract MyAction "[]" -p UserAccount@active`

so within my code I need a way to refer to the UserAccount.  `_self` seems to refer to the account that owns the contract

how can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .[emplace](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/3fddb727b8f3615917707281dfd3dd3cc5d3d66d/contracts/eosiolib/multi_index.hpp#L1657)() method's first parameter specifies the "payer" not the "scope" for data to be stored, the payer who pay for the RAM.

The multi_index [table's defination](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/3fddb727b8f3615917707281dfd3dd3cc5d3d66d/contracts/eosiolib/multi_index.hpp#L644-L646) specify the "code" and "scope".

To get the sender see this: [Account of caller of action](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1311/account-of-caller-of-action)

Comment: so I guess the answer is no, it can't be done, though the statement "As actions can be called with several user permissions at the same time there is no unique caller." doesn't make much sense.  if an action can be called with several user permissions (what for?) then an array of those permissions could be made available to the developer. this is important information without which developers are forced to pass in parameters that are redundant and could be erroneous

Comment: and thanks for the clarification with respect to "payer"

Comment: I now still have the same thoughts as you do on the sender question, so I just paste the link. I also check the system contract and see they usually pass the sender in.

Answer (score -1):

I just put the UserAccount as one of the arguments of the action

Comment: I understand I can do that, but since a authoritative account is required, that information should be available to me internally.  I'm asking whether/how it is