# Caller of action detail in code

Tags: smart-contract, accounts

I need to check Account of caller action ,as in ethereum we have a concept of msg.sender to get the caller eth_address, similar is there a way to get caller of action details in EOS.

Answer (score 0):

this question has been asked before.

see the answer in the link below:
[Account of caller of action](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1311/account-of-caller-of-action)

moderators will have to close this as a dupe